# How can I specify the path to Ninja in VS Code CMake configuration without modifying my system's PATH environment variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, ninja

As you can see I've tried a few approaches and none work:

**CMakeSettings.json**

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "riscv32",
            "generator": "Ninja"
        }
    ]
}
```

**cmake-kits.json**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "riscv32-esp-elf-gcc",
    "isTrusted": true,
    "compilers": {
      "C": "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/riscv32-esp-elf/esp-2022r1-11.2.0/riscv32-esp-elf/bin/riscv32-esp-elf-gcc.exe",
      "CXX": "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/riscv32-esp-elf/esp-2022r1-11.2.0/riscv32-esp-elf/bin/riscv32-esp-elf-g++.exe"
    },
    "toolchainFile": "/ProgramData/esp-idf/tools/cmake/toolchain-esp32c3.cmake",
    "preferredGenerator": {
      "name": "Ninja"
    }
  }
]
```

**settings.json**

```json
{

    "cmake.cmakePath": "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/cmake/3.24.0/bin/cmake.exe",
    "cmake.configureArgs": [
        "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/ninja/1.10.2/ninja.exe"
    ],
    "cmake.buildArgs": [
        "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/ninja/1.10.2/ninja.exe"
    ],
    "cmake.additionalCompilerSearchDirs": [
        "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/ninja/1.10.2"
    ]
}
```

On load I always get

```
[proc] The command: ninja --version failed with error: Error: spawn ninja ENOENT
[proc] The command: ninja-build --version failed with error: Error: spawn ninja-build ENOENT
[main] Unable to determine what CMake generator to use. Please install or configure a preferred generator, or update settings.json, your Kit configuration or PATH variable. Error: No usable generator found.
```

I want to avoid adding (yet another) entry to the operating system's `PATH`.

Comment: @user This is running in vscode, which makes everything (including `PATH` modifications) more difficult. There is only one installation of Ninja, but yes, the directory containing the Ninja executable is not in `PATH` and I don't intend on putting it there, since this executable is supposed to be application-specific to the Espressif embedded toolchain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was deeply frustrating, but I did eventually stumble into a solution.

Nothing in `settings.json` helps. The only setting that takes any effect is in `cmake-kits.json`:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "riscv32-esp-elf-gcc",
    "isTrusted": true,
    "compilers": {
      "C": "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/riscv32-esp-elf/esp-2022r1-11.2.0/riscv32-esp-elf/bin/riscv32-esp-elf-gcc.exe",
      "CXX": "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/riscv32-esp-elf/esp-2022r1-11.2.0/riscv32-esp-elf/bin/riscv32-esp-elf-g++.exe"
    },
    "toolchainFile": "/ProgramData/esp-idf/tools/cmake/toolchain-esp32c3.cmake",
    "preferredGenerator": {
      "name": "Ninja"
    },
    "environmentVariables": {
      "PATH": "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/ninja/1.10.2;${env:PATH}"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the system `PATH` environment variable, and you're not invoking CMake via commandline (in which case I'd suggest you wrap your commands with [`cmake -D env`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-env) to prepend to the `PATH`), and what you're trying isn't already working (you might want to try resetting the extensions state, which you can do with the `CMake: Reset CMake Tools Extension State` in the command palette), then you can try using [`${env:...}` VS Code variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables) in [CMake tools' `cmake.environment` setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#variable-substitution). Ex. `"cmake.environment": { "PATH": "<path-to-your-ninja>${pathSeparator}${env:PATH}" }`.

Comment: It's an interesting idea but it doesn't work. I've set `"cmake.environment": {
        "PATH": "/ProgramData/esp-idf-tools/tools/ninja/1.10.2:${env:PATH}"
    }` with no success.

Comment: `Invalid variable reference ${pathSeparator} in string`